# How to move a graph/array to the right

Tags: matplotlib

I've looked for various solutions to my problem but can't get any help. I'm creating a sine wave and cutting it up into buffers. Ie cutting it into parts. The program seems to run this fine but all the sections start from 0 opposed to the desired start point.

Code:

```
slice= 2048
arr2= arr1[:slice]    # 1st buffer from 0-2048
arr3= arr1[slice:2*slice]  #2nd buffer from 2048-4096



pylab.plot(arr2)   
pylab.draw()      
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(arr3)

pylab.show()
```

This prints the correct looking graphs for both parts but the 2nd graph starts at 0 (opposed to the range 2048-4096) 
I'm using the pylab.plot function- can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In your `plot()` function you need to specify the X axis:

```
pylab.plot(range(0,2048),arr2)   
pylab.draw()      
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(range(2048,4096),arr3)

pylab.show()
```

Comment: It is helpful to include a link to the documentation http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot